# Cant parse smart card Get Response (TLV)

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, tlv

I have been playing a little with a smart card i got, 
I did **SELECT** command on 3F00, and right after that **GET RESPONSE** command and
got this data: 
**85 17 00 01 00 00 00 12 12 00 00 01 03 01 01 00 60 60 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 00** 

I've tried to parse this TLV but couldn't understand the tag 85 and his meaning.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "SELECT command on 3F00"? Please post here the command APDU that returned that TLV.

Comment: If the answer really is from the card (any further information on the type would be helpful) there is no dependency from the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The smart card you have is somewhat uncooperative: It returns just a tag 85 (proprietary) with a data length of 0x17, followed by 90 00(okay). You have to refer to the manual of the card for further analysis.

Comment: You can get further information from [ISO7816-4](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx) in section 5.1.5 File control information.